# Sound coming after stopping rythmbox

Tags: 14.04, sound, rhythmbox, music

I was playing songs for approx. 25 mins and meanwhile I was working with too many pacakges like torrent downloader,Eclipse, Firefox ,File Browser and some other apps when I Stopped Rythmbox It didn't stop instead when I restarted it two diffrent Rythmboxes were playing simultaneously after closing one of them (which I could reach) was closed but the previous one which cannot be seen but heard is still playing till now what to do how to stop it?

I have tried

`ps aux | grep rhythmbox`

but no rythmbox is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons you aren't seeing anything is because it's `rhythmbox` instead of rythmbox.

The most viable theory is that there are two processes running. You can try:

`killall rhythmbox`.

Typos can be [dangerous](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?109390-True-Dangers-of-Running-as-Root&s=18065a1a324a971453b6acb868d2b0ad&p=619267#post619267).

Comment: kill all was helpful the typing mistake was only within question

Comment: I make that mistake too. :D